# Error reading 'id'

Tags: angular

I have an error from time to time:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
>       at eval (notebook.component.ts:88)
>       at Array.filter ()
>       at SafeSubscriber.eval [as _next] (notebook.component.ts:88)
>       at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:243)
>       at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:190)
>       at Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:131)
>       at Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:95)
>       at MapSubscriber._next (map.js:85)
>       at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:95)
>       at RefCountSubscriber.Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:131)

Error occurs after page load. If the page is reloaded, it will disappear. How can  get rid of it altogether?

ts:

```
  private loadNotebooks() {
    let filteredNotebooks;
    if (this.servNotebook) {
        this.servNotebook.getNotebooks().subscribe(notebook => {
            this.notebooks = notebook;
            this.filteredNotebooks = this.notebooks.filter((notebook) => notebook.user_id == this.authTokenService.currentUserData.id);
        });
    }
  }
```

html:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let notebook of filteredNotebooks">
  <ng-container *ngIf="authTokenService.currentUserData">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="header">
          <h4 class="title">{{notebook.title}}</h4>   
        </div>
        <div class="content" >
          <div [innerHTML]="notebook.description">
            {{ notebook.description }}
          </div>
          <hr />
          <div class="footer">
            <div class="stats">
              {{notebook.created_at | date: 'medium'}} 
            </div>
          </div>   
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

auth.service:

```
  import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
  import {Angular2TokenService} from 'angular2-token';
  import {Response} from '@angular/http';
  import {Subject} from 'rxjs/Subject';
  import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
  import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

  @Injectable()
  export class AuthService {

    userSignedIn$:Subject<boolean> = new Subject();

    constructor(private authService:Angular2TokenService) {
      this.authService.validateToken().subscribe(
        res => res.status === 200 ? this.userSignedIn$.next(res.json().success) : this.userSignedIn$.next(false)
    );
  }

    logOutUser():Observable<Response>{

      return this.authService.signOut().map(
          res => {
            this.userSignedIn$.next(false);
            return res;
          }
      );
    }

    logInUser(signInData: {email:string, password:string}):Observable<Response>{

      return this.authService.signIn(signInData).map(
          res => {
            this.userSignedIn$.next(true);
            return res
          }
      );

    }

    registerUser(signUpData:  {email:string, password:string, passwordConfirmation:string}):Observable<Response>{
      return this.authService.registerAccount(signUpData).map(
          res => {
            this.userSignedIn$.next(true);
            return res
          }
      );
    }

  }
```

Comment: are you using any View Child decorator to get element ref?

Comment: @Chellappan I use ViewContainerRef

Comment: 'currentUserData' is method??

Comment: @UnluckyAj Did not understand the question, it is used for authorized user `Angular2TokenService`

Comment: i know that but i am asking its a method or variable in authentication service??

Comment: @UnluckyAj it is in this component that I do not have variables and methods, I just import

Comment: can you share your authTokenService code

Comment: @Chellappan yes, updated the question

Comment: where is currentUserData is authentication service??

Comment: In your service file you don't have currentUserData variable from where are you getting that data?

Comment: @Chellappan I import the `import of {Angular2TokenService} from "angular2-token"`;

Comment: if you have currentUserData model try to optional operator